subpaths return 404 with nginx
I have a dockerized node js applicaiton on a ubuntu server with github ci/cd and i have setup reverse proxy with nginx and it works when i hit serverip but when i do something like serverip/aboutpage nginx return 404, so i tried hitting the docker container on my server with curl 0.0.0.0:8080/aboutpage and it return a valid response
here is the default file under etc/nginx/sites-available
root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:8080; #docker container ip 
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

Dockerfile
FROM node:22-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

USER node

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]

ci.yml
name: CI Pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Login Dockerhub
      env:
        DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME}}
        DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD}}
      run: docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build -t sm-api .
    - name: Tag Docker local image
      run: docker tag sm-api username/sm-api:latest
    - name: Push to Dockerhub
      run: docker push username/sm-api:latest


cd.yml
name: CD Pipeline

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["CI Pipeline"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - name: Pull Docker image
      run: sudo docker pull username/sm-api:latest
    - name: Delete Old docker container
      run: sudo docker rm -f sm-api-container || true
    - name: Run Docker Container
      run: sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name sm-api-container username/sm-api

my nodejs router index file
function MyRoutes(app, express){
    const router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('HomePage');
      });
    router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
        res.send('about');
      });
    
      return router;
}
module.exports = {
    WebRoutes
};

everything works fine locally

You have proxy_pass and try_files in the same location block. Try removing the try_files statement.

thanks man it worked, i was looking for a solution for past 2 days. i'm new to nginx

removed
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

from default file, It work now
